# java calling a class from another class within same package

Tags: java

So I was following this tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

I cloned their repositories for  the software for fear of mistyping something.
The code does not work when I compile Greeter.java using `javac` and then use `java` to run HelloWorld.java  file It gives me the following error:

```
HelloWorld.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class HelloWorld
2 errors
```

I tried explicitly importing Greeter into HelloWorld using
`ìmport hello.Greeter`
The code works fine when I run it without the `package hello;`statements.

Any idea why I am getting this error??

So I followed through with the tutorial and using `mvn package` command and the jar file generated the project works.

So  is this issue with trying to compile it with java command in the command line.

Adding directory structure of the project

```
pom.xml src     target

./src:
main

./src/main:
java

./src/main/java:
hello

./src/main/java/hello:
Greeter.java    HelloWorld.java
```

Comment: show code of both classes

Comment: If you are unable to compile ```Greeter```, you will not be able to run the ```HelloWorld``` class either. Makes sense! Now, how are you trying to compile the greeter class? What is your working directory and what is your javac command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you try to compile the sources while you're in the directory `src/test/java/hello`. That's the wrong directory, you have to do it from directory `src/test/java` and pass the directory (i.e. package) to the compiler, e.g.

```
javac hello/*.java
```

Another reason might be that you haven't compiled `Greeter.java`, so the compiler doesn't find the class-file while compiling `Hello.java`. Above command should solve that.

If you have a main method in hello run
`java hello/name-of-file.java`
to run your main method.